# Fancybox YOutube Video Keeps Playing

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Not sure what the catch is but in FF the video keeps playing. All other browsers close when you click outside of fancybox... the embeded Youtube Video will stop playing as well. Firefox seems to ignore this. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
     callbackOnClose: function() {
     $("#fancy_content").html(" ");
     } 
});

    });
    $("#fancy_content").empty();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0,
                    opacity: 0.3,
                    css: {'background-color': '#cdc3b7'}
                }
               }
                 });
                 });
```

Comment: Some help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't have to initialize the same `.fancybox` selector twice. In other words, you don't have to do :

  ```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     // options
  });
  ```

  ... and later :

  ```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  ```
- `#fancy_content` is not a valid fancybox selector (at least not for v2.x)
- `$("#fancy_content").empty();` is outside of the `.ready()` method. Anyway is useless as explained above.
- `callbackOnClose` is not a valid API option (use `afterClose` instead if needed)
- This script works perfectly fine cross-browser :

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
        /*
        // yo don't need this
        ,
        callbackOnClose: function() {
          $("#fancy_content").html(" ");
        }
        */
    });
```

... as you can see in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5GBJ/)**. Make sure you test it with FF (works fine with my FF v17.0.1)

Comment: This is fine but I have other things within my inline div like text, bulleted list etc. My youtube vid is just embedded. So when the inline div pops up with the lightbox, the youtube vid is simply embeded above the text. When you close he box, the embeded vid still plays.

Comment: @MizAkita : you never said you were targeting inline content neither you posted any html code. Please post all the necessary code and don't let people, who is trying to help, to guess what you have and what you need. Personally I think is a bad idea to have inline videos because they impact you page load and performance regardless that they are visible or not.